# Main page route is always highlighted on Vaadin

Tags: css, spring-boot, vaadin

I have a problem with Vaadin MainLayout. I use Vaadin with Spring Boot to create a UI for my backend. I created a layout used this [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/tutorial/navigation-and-layouts) documentation to style the page.

```
a[highlight] {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

In my project, even if I go to another page the main layout stays highlighted with bold and underline on the drawer which of the page. Here is my route annotation of the main page.

```
@Route(value = "", layout = MainLayout.class)
```

If I add a value to Route the problem solves but I don't want to add a value because it is the main page. How can I solve it with editing CSS. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RouterLink` has an odd default for marking routes as active, highlighting any routes that start with the same path as active. Because, presumably, your main view is mapped to an empty string, it will always match. You can override the highlight condition like this:

```java
var link = new RouterLink();
link.setHighlightCondition(HighlightConditions.sameLocation());
```

There is an issue about the functionality: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/13256